# Does the RCD go before or after the MCB?

Tags: power-supply, rcd, electric-vehicle

I am going to connect a 4 pole RCD and MCB to the input of a power supply.  Which one should I connect first, the RCD or the MCB? I have seen them connected both ways.

Comment: Which RCD, which MCB, which power supply, how are you going to wire them, and why would a power supply need either an MCB or RCD on the mains input?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want to protect multiple MCB circuits with a single RCD.    (For economic reasons)
This dictates the RCD comes first, then the MCB and finally the cabling the MCB protects to the loads.

Of course the RCD must be suitable for the current and short circuit rating of the protection in front.

*Domestic electrical code in the Netherlands allows up to 4 circuits per 30mA RCD.*